# Need to store a particular column from excel sheet in java

Tags: java, excel, apache, row

I am trying to read an excel sheet using java, I want to read the first row and find a particular word in the row and read that particular column in a list/array and perform further computations. Here is my code to read the excel sheet, i have used poi apache libraries.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelSheetReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        String excelFilePath = "book.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

if(cell.getStringCellValue() == "Mitesh") {   // why this is not working?
                            columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
                            System.out.println("\nCELL: " + columnIndex);
                        }

if(nextRow.getRowNum() > 0){ //To filter column headings
                    if(cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex) {// cell.getColumnIndex() == 1){// To match column index: columnIndex, cell.getStringCellValue() == "Coverge"
                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            columnData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            columnData.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "POP");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "PIP");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "PEP");
                        break;
                }
                //System.out.print(" - ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if(cell.getStringCellValue() == "Mitesh") {   // why this is not working?

There are two problems in this line. 
1. it's string.equals("Mitesh")
2. you have to check the cells' type before calling .getStringCellValue()

This should work:

```
    private String[] getColumnAsArray(Sheet sheet, String header) {
    List<String> values=new ArrayList<>();

    int columnOfIntrest=-1;

    //find the interresting column
        for(Cell cell:sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum())){
            if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING && 
                    cell.getStringCellValue().equals("Mitesh")) {  //this is working
                columnOfIntrest = cell.getColumnIndex();
                break;
            }
        }
        //nothing found
        if(columnOfIntrest<0)
            return null;
        Iterator<Row> rowIter=sheet.iterator();

        if(rowIter.hasNext())
            rowIter.next(); //skip the first row

        while(rowIter.hasNext()){
            Cell currCell=rowIter.next().getCell(columnOfIntrest);

            switch (currCell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                values.add(currCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                values.add(Boolean.toString(currCell.getBooleanCellValue()));
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                values.add(Double.toString(currCell.getNumericCellValue()));
                break;
            }
        }

    return values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What's the actual problem?

Note: You're not reading formula values... for that you'll need something like:

```
int cellType = (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) 
    ? cell.getCachedFormulaResultType() : cell.getCellType();

switch (cellType) {
   ...
   default: System.out.println("Unhandeled cell type " + cellType);
}
```

Comment: I am facing problem in reading numeric values as strings. do i need to attach formula values also in my code?

Comment: ok i have added formula value also in my code, but how to store a particular column values to an array?

Comment: I am getting an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell, how can i get numeric value as a string?